# Parse TXT File with local paths to copy these to a folder

Tags: parsing, batch-file, copy, notepad

I've been copying favorite songs for "THE MOST AWESOME CAR CD EVER" into a txt file. All the files are exact paths to the music.
Now i want to parse the txt and copy what it finds into a folder... i`m not that fluent in batch so maybe you could help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("yourtextfilename.txt") do (
   ECHO XCOPY "%%i" "c:\yourdestfolder\"
)
```

for each line in the filename, where the filename is in double-quotes (`usebackq`) assign each line of the file to `%%i` in turn and `XCOPY` that file to `c:\yourdestfolder\`

The **PROPOSED** XCOPY will be echoed to the screen. This is deliberate to allow you to make sure that is what you want to do. To **EXECUTE** the `XCOPY` simply delete the `ECHO` keyword before it. If the "1 files copied" response irritates you, add `>nul`  after `"c:\yourdestfolder\"` if you want to suppress the message.

"c:\yourdestfolder\" will be CREATED by XCOPY if it does not already exist. XCOPY will ask whether you want to overwrite existing files if there is already a file with the same name in "c:\yourdestfolder\" - which is why you may *NOT* want to suppress the messages.